# Azure Disk not listing in portal

Tags: azure, amazon-ebs

I have a few queries with disks in Azure,i find it hard to relate it to AWS EBS.

i am unable to view the disks attached to a VM(though i have reached maximum disks attached error) . it lists in teh Operating system, but not in portal, how can i get a refreshed view?

can i attach or deattach a vhd from storage account blade?( i want to manage the disks out of VM blade)?

I cannot see the disks attached to which VM in storage account blade, is there a hack for that if i want to see this in portal?

thanks!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> it lists in teh Operating system, but not in portal, how can i get a
>   refreshed view?

We can find the **disks** in VM --> **Disks** blade in azure portal:
[image]

> can i attach or deattach a vhd from storage account blade?

For now, we **can't** manager disks from storage account blade, but we can via the VM -->disks blade to attach or deattach a VHD.

[image]

> I cannot see the disks attached to which VM in storage account blade,
>   is there a hack for that if i want to see this in portal?

If you attach **an new empty VHD** to Azure VM via portal, the VHD name same as "VMname2017042000.VHD". So, we can find the VHD attached to wchich VM from storage account blade.
[image]

If you attach **an existing VHD** to Azure VM, we can use power shell to get the disk information:

```
PS C:\Users> (get-azurermvm -ResourceGroupName vm -Name jasonvm).StorageProfile | fl *

ImageReference : Microsoft.Azure.Management.Compute.Models.ImageReference
OsDisk         : Microsoft.Azure.Management.Compute.Models.OSDisk
DataDisks      : {jasonvm-20170420-091920}
```

**Update**:

According to your description, your VMs and disks are in the ASM module, we can use this PowerShell command to check the disk attached to which VM.

```
PS C:\Users> Get-AzureDisk


AffinityGroup        :
AttachedTo           : RoleName: DemoVS8172016
                       DeploymentName: DemoVS8172016
                       HostedServiceName: DemoVS8172016
IsCorrupted          : False
Label                :
Location             : East US
DiskSizeInGB         : 128
MediaLink            : https://1qportalvhdsxxyczk0sy961.blob.core.windows.net/vhds/DemoVS8172016-DemoVS8172016-2016-08-17.vhd
DiskName             : DemoVS8172016-DemoVS8172016-0-201608171422040377
SourceImageName      : 03f55de797f546a1b29d1b8d66be687a__VS-2013-Prem-VSU5-AzureSDK-282-WS2012R22016-07-12
OS                   : Windows
IOType               : Standard
OperationDescription : Get-AzureDisk
OperationId          : 4317b875-87c4-afe1-936b-fb698012f88a
OperationStatus      : Succeeded

AffinityGroup        :
AttachedTo           : RoleName: jasontest321
                       DeploymentName: jasontest321
                       HostedServiceName: jasontest321
IsCorrupted          : False
Label                :
Location             : East US
DiskSizeInGB         : 30
MediaLink            : https://1qportalvhdsxxyczk0sy961.blob.core.windows.net/vhds/jasontest321-jasontest321-2017-04-24.vhd
DiskName             : jasontest321-jasontest321-0-201704240500400008
SourceImageName      : b39f27a8b8c64d52b05eac6a62ebad85__Ubuntu-14_04_5-LTS-amd64-server-20170405-en-us-30GB
OS                   : Linux
IOType               : Standard
OperationDescription : Get-AzureDisk
OperationId          : 4317b875-87c4-afe1-936b-fb698012f88a
OperationStatus      : Succeeded
```

Comment: Please let me know if you would like further assistance.

Comment: for my first question, i didnt get any options as such please check this link for screenshot. i suppose the portal is new for me!!! https://www.screencast.com/t/ZWnUtlpDW0RS

Comment: @Pasha we can use PowerShell command to get azure disk `Get-AzureDisk` in the command return, we can find the disk attached to which VM. I have update my answer, please check it.

Comment: Yes, i did get disks from powershell, but i found the ARM has issues. it does not reflect many changes.

Comment: @Pasha if the disks in ARM, we should use `(get-azurermvm -ResourceGroupName vm -Name jasonvm).StorageProfile | fl *` to check, ASM different from ARM,